# how to pass image and label from one viewController to tableViewCell swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, uikit

Hi im trying to pass data from one viewController to tableViewCell without using the segue, i tried with delegate and nsNotificationCenter but it did not work with me so, help me please.

this is my code for the view controller which i want to pass data from it ( imageViewSweet, LabelSweet )

```
   import UIKit


  class sweetAndSalty4ViewController: UIViewController {




@IBOutlet var imageViewSweet: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet var labelsweet: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var sweeetTable: UITableView!


 var passText: String?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    
    passText = labelsweet.text
    
    
    
    super.viewDidLoad()

  

}




@IBAction func sendData(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
     let sb = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cartVC") as!       cartViewController
      sb.priceLabel = labelsweet
    present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil)

    

                
      }
  





 }
```

and this is the code for the viewController which i want to display the image and the label from the swwetAndSalty4ViewController .

```
  import UIKit

  class cartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!

var passText: String?

var cartItem = ""


@IBOutlet var cartTable: UITableView!



      override func viewDidLoad() {
          

          cartTable.delegate = self
          cartTable.dataSource = self
          
          
               
             
                   //  foodTable.separatorStyle = .none

          
          view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 228/255, green: 230/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1)
                   navigationItem.title = "My Cart"
          
          super.viewDidLoad()
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          
          
          return cartItem.count
      }








      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          240
      }
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          
          
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell") as! cartTableViewCell
          
          
        
          
              cell.layer.cornerRadius = 30
                 
                 cell.layer.borderWidth = 15.0
                 cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                 
                 
                 
        cell.cartImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
                 cell.cartImage.layer.cornerRadius = 2
                 cell.cartImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                 cell.cartImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                 
                 
                 
                 cell.cartLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .medium)
                 
                 cell.cartLabel.textColor = .black
                 cell.cartLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          cell.cartLabel.backgroundColor = .systemGray5
                
                 
                 
                 cell.cartLabel.text = ""
                 cell.cartImage.image = UIImage(named: "")
             
                 
          
               //  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
                
                 
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          return cell
          
      }
      
  
  
  
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, i've also organized your code:
First View Controller:

```
import UIKit

struct myVariables {
    static var kinder: String! = nil
    static var kinderImage: UIImage! = nil
}

class sweetAndSalty4ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageViewSweet: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var labelsweet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var sweeetTable: UITableView!
    
    var passText: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        passText = labelsweet.text
    }

    @IBAction func sendData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let sb = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cartVC") as!       cartViewController
         sb.priceLabel = labelsweet
       present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func sendDataToMyVariables(kinder: String, kinderImage: UIImage) {
        myVariables.kinder = kinder
        myVariables.kinderImage = kinderImage
    }
    
 }
```

and then, after you send the variables you can use them anywhere in your code by doing

```
myVariables.kinder // get the string
myVariables.kinderImage // get the image
```